# Is Daemon Tools Safe?

Tags: windows, virus

I downloaded Daemon tools from the official site (the first one that comes up in google, its www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads) and when I clicked the download link Norton said that the site I was downloading the exe from was a known malicious site (something like soft24.com).  It was talking about the mirror that was actually serving the file.

Anyway, I installed it on my server - and now I feel like I should reimage my server since I have tainted it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately anti-virus software is not the smartest piece of software out there, and is really an annoyance to most Super Users.  Although anti-virus software is necessary for keeping your PC safe, the user must realize that all "threats" it detects may not really be a threat.  Daemon tools is a safe piece of software and is used by many.

I personally use [SlySoft's Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) and may be an alternative to DTOOLS, but I have also used Daemon tools before with no issues.

Comment: The feeling of distrust for DT started when I went to the download page and the AD they place right below the tiny download link was a "Download Now" button.

Comment: @Blackasaurus One of the reasons why I switched to CloneDrive

Answer (score 2):

I never had any troubles for installing DTools, and NOD32 hasn't detected anything.

So, to aswear your question: Yes, Daemon Tools is safe :) .

Comment: safe when downloaded from official mirrors

Answer (score 1):

Upload the file to this site, see what it finds.

http://www.virustotal.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply uninstall the daemon tool, then scan your server with a good security tool. Not need to reinstall your server.

Comment: Depends on how nasty the infection is or it it is a new undetectable rootkit or infection that will take up to a month for scanner dats to be updated to detect it.